# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении: " Хотя(,) это, наверное, комплекс Дон Кихота..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь "хотя" - это всё-таки союз. Вероятно, наблюдается явление парцелляции. Опущена первая (главная) часть предложения, а союз ***хотя*** начинает второе (придаточное) предложение. Запятую в сложноподчинённом предложении ставят перед союзом, а не после него. Поэтому после ХОТЯ знак не ставим.

Деепричастие ***хотя*** в современном русском языке мы заменяем словом "желая". Но у дедушки Крылова пример употребления ***хотя*** как деепричастия мы видим: "Но, делу дать хотя (=желая - Е.К.) законный вид и толк, кричит..." ("Волк и Ягнёнок").

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Никаких условий для нее нет.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть, вы подумали, что "хотя" - это деепричастие, но, спешу разочаровать, такого деепричастия не существует. В русском языке это слово бывает либо союзом, либо частицей, коей и является в вашем, уважаемый вопрошающий, предложении, и означает она *"по крайней мере"*.